# Python3 string format assignment lead to referenced before assignment

Tags: python, format-string

I understand that there exist numbers of posts about referenced before assignment with increments.

However, I see a similar issue with format string.

```
greeting = "hello, {}"

def printHello(name):
   greet = greeting.format(name)
   print(greet)

printHello("Erica")
```

I have `local variable 'greet' referenced before assignment`.

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

Also, this error occurs once in a while so it's not deterministic...

I assume `global greeting` will fix the issue?

== edited ==

I have found that the error was coming from one of the library not my code
sorry for confusion

Comment: Your code as-is doesn't produce that error message because it enters an infinite recursion (you're calling `print` at the bottom of a function you named `print` with no exit condition). Can you post the simplest, self-contained example that actually produces the error (even unreliably)?

Comment: Why you are using function name as print.? There is a call to print in your code which will lead to inifinite loop.

Comment: If your code actually produces that error, then the code in the question isn't the code you ran. Please include the actual code that produces the error.

Comment: sorry. that was mistake, I had no recursion issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you have re-defined `print` and hence it is going in a recursion. 
Changing the function name to something else, should solve the problem

```
greeting = "hello, {}"

def printHello(name):
    greet = greeting.format(name)
    print(greet)
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, the original code does not the above code. I updated the code.